How to deserialize with relations
I am using the Symfony serializer to denormalize JSON data and create an entity with relations.
My json body looks like this:
{
    "user": "1",
    "prop1": "string"
}

This is my entity:
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use App\Repository\ClassARepository;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\Groups;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: ClassARepository::class)]
class ClassA
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column]
    private ?int $id = null;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['default'])]
    private ?User $user = null;

    #[ORM\Column(length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['default'])]
    private ?string $prop1 = null;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?User
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser(?User $user): static
    {
        $this->user = $user;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getProp1(): ?string
    {
        return $this->prop1;
    }

    public function setProp1(?string $prop1): static
    {
        $this->prop1 = $prop1;

        return $this;
    }
}

And this my code in the controller to set the serializer:
$defaultContext = [AbstractNormalizer::GROUPS => ['default']];
        $classMetadataFactory = new ClassMetadataFactory(new AttributeLoader());
        $encoder = new JsonEncoder();

        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer($classMetadataFactory, null, null, null, null, null, $defaultContext);
        $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [$encoder]);

Now when executing the request to api endpoint, i'm running into the error:
Failed to denormalize attribute \"user\" value for class \"App\\Entity\\ClassA\": Expected argument of type \"?App\\Entity\\User\", \"string\" given at property path \"user\".

How can I handle the user id string from json to convert to the specific user entity?
I tried to use the ReflectionExtractor in ObjectNormalizer, but then my response looks like this:
App\Entity\ClassA {#751
  -id: null
  -user: 
App\Entity
\
User {#808
    -id: null
    -email: null
    -roles: []
    -password: null
  }
  -prop1: "string"
}


You first need tell the serializer what the user object is. It does not know how to (de)serialize it.
This should give you and idea what i mean:
$serializer->deserialize($userObject, User::class, 'json');

Once it can (de)serialze this it knows how to insert it into ClassA.
